# Касаемо/касательно

Tags: употребление-слов

В каких случаях варьируется употребление?

(пример - касаемо того, что ... / либо касательно того, что .... )
Нашёл аналогичный вопрос на просторах интернета, где указано, что это вообще старорусские архаические формы , образованные от слова "касается".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, действительно, это старорусские архаичные формы.  касаемо [касаемо] предлог разг.-сниж. То же, что: касательно.(Современный толковый словарь русского языка Т.Ф.Ефремовой); с предлогом ''до'' или без него, предлог с род. п. (простореч., обл.). То же, что касательно. (Толковый словарь русского языка Д.Н.Ушакова ).

А это ответ справки.
Вопрос № 177168

Мне кажется, что выражение "Что касаемо /чего-то, кого-то" является по-крайней мере просторечным. К сожалению, нигде не могу найти что-нибудь, доказывающее это либо обратное. Не могли бы Вы пояснить так ли это, если можно, приведите, пожалуйста, какие-либо источники. Спасибо!

Natalia

---

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Вы правы. Касаемо - просторечный предлог (это зафиксировано в словарях русского языка). Стилистически нейтрально и общеупотребительно: что касается (кого-чего)

Answer (score 0):

Значения слов "касаемо" и "касательно" разные, если обратиться к словарю С. И. Ожегова, "касаемо" сущ. касание, т. е. точка касания (дотрагивания физически). "Касательство" значит причастность к чему-нибудь, отношение к кому-нибудь.